# Formatting needs to be done in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below pdf report which is formed by an xsl file and that xsl file defines the style for this pdf report below is the url please look at the pdf report ..
[Pdf Report](http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/4551/50782943.jpg)

The xsl file which is used is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" extension-element-prefixes="set" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-width="21cm" page-height="29.7cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
           <fo:region-body margin-bottom="2cm" margin-top="4cm"/>
          <fo:region-after extent="2cm"/>
          <fo:region-before extent="4cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
              </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" initial-page-number="1">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" 
                               text-align="left" font-size="9pt"  >
               </fo:block>
          <fo:block font-size="9pt" text-align="end">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-column column-width="9.5cm"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="9.5cm"/>
               <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell
                                        text-align="center">
                    <fo:block text-align="left">
                                            Run:
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(  DepartmentSalesReport/CurrentDate , 6, 2 )" />
                                        /
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(  DepartmentSalesReport/CurrentDate , 9, 2 )" />
                                        /
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(  DepartmentSalesReport/CurrentDate , 1, 4 )" />
                                        @
                                    <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/currentTime" />
                                        </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                   <fo:table-cell text-align="right">
                    <!--fo:block space-before="8mm">
                      <xsl:text>Keep this report for 6 months</xsl:text>
                    </fo:block-->
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell >
                    <fo:block space-before="8mm">Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="terminator"/></fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>

          </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
          <fo:block text-align-last="center" space-after="1.5cm">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-column column-width="4cm"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="10cm"/>
               <fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>
               <fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>
              <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell  font-size="9pt">
                    <fo:block>Store Number:
                      <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/store_code"/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                   <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                             <fo:block  text-align-last="center" font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold" space-after="1mm">
                                <fo:inline text-decoration="underline">Department Sales Report</fo:inline>
                               </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell text-align="right"   font-size="9pt">
                     <fo:block > 
                        <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/tradingday"/>   
                     </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell text-align="right" font-size="9pt">
                    <xsl:variable name="date"><xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/tradingdate"/></xsl:variable>
                    <fo:block> 
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($date,5,2)"/>/<xsl:value-of select="substring($date,7,2)"/>/<xsl:value-of select="substring($date,1,4)"/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
          <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-column column-width="19cm"/>
          <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                   <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                                      <fo:block text-align-last="center" font-size="9pt" >
                                        Summary of Sales by department, only those
                                            departments with activity (Sales,
                                            refunds, voids) will appear on this
                                            report.Use this report to monitor sales in
                                            key departments and make merchandising
                                            decisions as needed.
                          </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
          </fo:block>
          <fo:block font-size="9pt" >
           <fo:table table-layout="fixed" >
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.8cm" 
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9"> <fo:block color="black"
                        space-before.optimum="-8pt">
                        <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" 
                               text-align="left" font-size="9pt"  />

                    </fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row font-weight="bold">
                                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="left"><xsl:text>-------------------------Department-------------------</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>Net Sales</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>Qty</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>% of Sales</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>--------Void--------</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>-------Return-------</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>        
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-row font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:text>Description</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Qty</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Qty</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row >
                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9" > <fo:block color="black"
                        space-before.optimum="-8pt">

                    </fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>

                            </fo:table-body>
                            </fo:table>
          </fo:block>
          <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" 
                               text-align="left" font-size="9pt"  />



     </fo:static-content>


        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <xsl:variable name="storeSales" select="sum(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentDesc/netSales)"/>
        <br/>
          <!--          <fo:block font-size="9pt" space-after="3mm" break-before="page">-->
            <xsl:for-each select="DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentDesc">
                    <fo:block font-size="9pt" space-after="1mm">
                    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" >
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.8cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <xsl:variable name="levelNo"><xsl:value-of select="levelNbr"/></xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name="levelCheck"><xsl:value-of select="level"/></xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:if test="$levelCheck!=''">
                                    <xsl:if test="$levelNo='2'">
                                    <fo:table-row>  
                                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9">
                                    <fo:block>
                                           <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                                    </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:if>
                     <fo:table-row >
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="level"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>

                                        <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="$levelNo!='2'">
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="prgpName"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                    ***DEPT TOTAL*** </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(netSales,'0.00')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(prodCount,'0')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>


                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <xsl:variable name="salesPercentage"><xsl:value-of select="format-number((netSales div $storeSales)*100, '###,##0')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$salesPercentage='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$salesPercentage!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$salesPercentage"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(postVoidQuantity,'0')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(postVoidAmount,'0.00')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(returnQuantity,'0')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(returnAmount,'0.00')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                        <xsl:if test="$levelNo='2'">
                                    <fo:table-row>  
                                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9">
                                    <fo:block>
                                           <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                                    </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:if>
                    </fo:table-body>

                  </fo:table>
                </fo:block>

            </xsl:for-each>
        <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" 
                               text-align="left" font-size="9pt"  />
           <fo:block  font-size="9pt" space-after="1mm" space-before="2mm">

<fo:table>
<fo:table-column column-width="1.5cm"/>
<fo:table-column column-width="4.5cm"/>

<fo:table-header>
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block font-weight="bold"></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
     <fo:block text-align="left" space-after="1.5mm">
     <xsl:text>DEPARTMENT TOTALS</xsl:text></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
</fo:table-header>

<fo:table-body>
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block><xsl:text>SS SALES</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/store_code"/></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block><xsl:text>CIGARETTE SALES</xsl:text></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block space-after="1.5mm"><xsl:text>LIQUOR SALES</xsl:text></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block><xsl:text>TOTAL FRONT END SALES</xsl:text></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>

</fo:table-body>

</fo:table>

</fo:block>



              <fo:block space-before="5mm" text-align="center" font-size="9pt" font-weight="bold" id="terminator">
                 <xsl:text></xsl:text>
          </fo:block>

        </fo:flow>

      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I have added new rows in the current report as shown in this link ,..[Modified Report](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/sdfdu.jpg/), But please advise As you also mite have seen that I want the 59997 to be printed at the front of SS  SALES as indicated with red arrow also please advise what modifications need to be done in xsl to achieve that ,For knowlegde purpose that numeric value is 59997 is coming  from in xsl  `<fo:block><xsl:text>SS SALES</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/store_code"/></fo:block>` Please advise how to show the value in front and what formatting eed to be done in present xsl for this.

Please advise guys as I am stuck because of this..!!Any help will be appreciated from my bottom of heart.!!

Below is the xml , Please review it ..!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report Name="DepartmentSalesReport" Title="Department Sales Report"
    Description="Department Sales Report" Version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <InitParam Name="tradingdate" Type="java.lang.String" />
      <InitParam Name="tradingday" Type="java.lang.String" />
      <ReportBand BandType="HeaderBand" Name="DepartmentSalesReportBand">
        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="OutletSQL">
        <DataField Name="store_code" Type="Data" FieldName="ORGU_CODE" />
        </ReportElement>
        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="InitParams">
        <DataField Name="tradingdate" Type="Data" FieldName="tradingdate" />
        </ReportElement>
        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="InitParams">
        <DataField Name="tradingday" Type="Data" FieldName="tradingday" />
        </ReportElement>
    </ReportBand>
    <ReportBand BandType="DetailBand" Name="Terminal">
        <ReportElement Type="Detail" Name="DepartmentDesc" DataSource="DataSql">
            <DataField Name="level" Type="Data" FieldName="LEVEL"/>
            <DataField Name="levelNbr" Type="Data" FieldName="LEVELNBR"/>
            <DataField Name="prgpName" Type="Data" FieldName="PRGP_NAME"/>
            <DataField Name="prodCount" Type="Data" FieldName="PROD_COUNT"/>
            <DataField Name="netSales" Type="Data" FieldName="NET_SALES"/>
            <DataField Name="postVoidQuantity" Type="Data" FieldName="POST_VOID_QUANTITY"/>
            <DataField Name="postVoidAmount" Type="Data" FieldName="POST_VOID_AMOUNT"/>
            <DataField Name="returnQuantity" Type="Data" FieldName="RETURN_QUANTITY"/>
            <DataField Name="returnAmount" Type="Data" FieldName="RETURN_AMOUNT"/>  

        </ReportElement>

        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="DateSQL">
            <DataField Name="CurrentDate" Type="Data" FieldName="1" />
            <DataField Name="currentTime" Type="Data" FieldName="2" />
        </ReportElement>
    </ReportBand>
    <DataSource
        Type="walgreens.pos.maintenance.eod.DepartmentSalesReportDataSource"
        Name="DataSql"
        Statement="">
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource
        Type="com.pcmsgroup.v21.star.framework.application.reports.SpringReadOnlySQLStatement"
        Name="OutletSQL"
        Statement="select ORGU_CODE,OUTL_TRADE_DATE from outlet,org_unit where outlet.OUTL_ID = org_unit.OUTL_ID">
    </DataSource>

    <DataSource
        Type="com.pcmsgroup.v21.star.framework.application.reports.SpringReadOnlySQLStatement"
        Name="DateSQL"
        Statement="SELECT current date,current time FROM sysibm.sysdummy1">
    </DataSource>

</Report>
```

Comment: Without seeing the input XML, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For looking at the XSLT that is generating your XSL-FO, there are a number of separate tables involved, with the list of departments in the report being a separate table to your totals at the moment. For the table listing the departments, there are nine columns

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed">
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="6cm" text-align="center"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.8cm"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm" text-align="center"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
   <fo:table-body>
```

However, for your department totals, the table only has two columns

```
<fo:table>
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.5cm"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="4.5cm"/>
   <fo:table-header>
```

I suspect you really want three columns here, which correspond in length to the first three columns of the department list table

```
<fo:table
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="6cm"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
   <fo:table-header>
```

Then, for example, for your total rows, instead of doing this...

```
<fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block/>
   </fo:table-cell>
   <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
         <xsl:text>SS SALES</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/store_code"/>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
 </fo:table-row>
```

You just add a new table cell

```
<fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block/>
   </fo:table-cell>
   <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
         <xsl:text>SS SALES</xsl:text>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
   <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
         <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/store_code"/>
      </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
 </fo:table-row>
```

You would probably need to do this for all the rows in your final 'totals' table